# org.json.XML cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, package

I am using JSON in my android application and have been using the org.json.JSONObject and org.json.JSONException classes, however org.json.XML seems to be missing from my distribution of json, or I am using the wrong package?

Comment: Your title uses "xml" in lower case, but you mention org.json.XML in the body. Which are you trying to use?

Comment: Upper case, Fixed to avoid confusion